# Getting model property using custom field names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with properties like this

```
[Display(Name = "Option Value 1")]
public string option_value1;
[Display(Name = "Option Value 2")]
public string option_value2;
[Display(Name = "Option Value 3")]
public string option_value3;
[Display(Name = "Option Value 4")]
public string option_value4;

...
...
[Display(Name = "Option Value n")]
public string option_valuen;
```

And I want to do something in views like

```
for (i = 0;i < n; i++) {
if (Model.getProperty("Option_Value"+i) != null) 
{
then display "Option_Value"+i
}
```

I can do it very smooth in cakephp, is that possible in ASP.NET MVC too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it, if you can't use an array, is to use weakly typed versions of `HtmlHelpers` :

```
@for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     @Html.Display("option_value" + i)
}
```

You can replace `Display` with `Editor` if you want a textbox for edition purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible by using an array. Instead of creating a separate property for each of the options, you should have one property in your model:

```
public string[] Options { get; set; }
```

Then you will be able to loop through it and access the options with an index.

When creating inputs for that string, you have to use a for loop with an index to get MVC to generate the right id and name attributes of the inputs:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Length)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! As I am using EF DB first, what if I cannot add an array to the model and the properties are not able to changed. Can I access property by custom name in MVC view?

Comment: In that case it's probably better to bypass the model binder and use `Form["Option_Value" + i]` to get the values. Or create a view model with a sane information model that does the mapping to the db (which doesn't look very well designed)